# How to describe an "incomplete" prior?

Tags: terminology, likelihood, prior, marginal-distribution

I would like to know how to describe sources of uncertainty neglected when I approximate a prior distribution $p(x)$ by a marginal distribution. Specifically, let's say that I have a marginal likelihood $p\left(\mathbf{x}|\phi,\mathbf{u},\mathbf{f}\right)$. I can obtain $p(\mathbf{x})$ by integrating,

$p(\mathbf{x}) = \int p\left(\mathbf{x}|\phi,\mathbf{u},\mathbf{f}\right)p(\phi)\: p(\mathbf{u})\: p(\mathbf{f})\: d\phi \: d\mathbf{u} \: d\mathbf{f}$.

But if instead I integrate over only one of the dependent variables,

$p(\mathbf{x|\mathbf{u},\mathbf{f}}) = \int p\left(\mathbf{x}|\phi,\mathbf{u},\mathbf{f}\right)\: p(\phi)\:d\phi$

then I am left with an estimate of $p(\mathbf{x})$ that is still a marginal probability.

What is the term for the variables $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{f}$ in this context? Lurking? Latent?